# Convert object to JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest

Is there a simple method to convert any object to JSON in Android?

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Most people are using gson : [check this](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObj);
```

Comment: Why we have no embedded method for toJson?  But we have for fromJson ?

Comment: try to use gson they have it.

Comment: But it is very complicated if you want to offuscate your code

Answer (score 64):

```
public class Producto {

int idProducto;
String nombre;
Double precio;



public Producto(int idProducto, String nombre, Double precio) {

    this.idProducto = idProducto;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;

}
public int getIdProducto() {
    return idProducto;
}
public void setIdProducto(int idProducto) {
    this.idProducto = idProducto;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public Double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}
public void setPrecio(Double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String toJSON(){

    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("id", getIdProducto());
        jsonObject.put("nombre", getNombre());
        jsonObject.put("precio", getPrecio());

        return jsonObject.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: i prefer this way, each object has their own stringify method, thank you for the insight !.

Answer (score 14):

Might be better choice:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(this, Producto.class);
}
```

Comment: Why is this a better choice?

Comment: Wanting to be able to convert an object to a JSON string does not necessarily mean you want the object's string representation to always be JSON.

Comment: @NeriaNachum, The thing was in my mind when I answered having a class with a lot of attributes. Overriding its `toString()` method creates many String objects when you print in default way - generated by Android Studio or IntelliJ Idea - however, this is one line of code and using power of GsonBuilder.

Comment: @Thizzer, You are absolutely right. I was thinking it is good to be shared and seen by developers (those who aren't familiar with approach at least). Then they will use whenever they need.

Comment: I too feel this as better choice as the conversion can be handled from the model itself, abstracting out the implementation.

Answer (score 12):

download the library Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
```

To use the library in a method.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

//transform a java object to json
System.out.println("json =" + gson.toJson(Object.class).toString());

//Transform a json to java object
String json = string_json;
List<Object> lstObject = gson.fromJson(json_ string, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) do this using RestTemplate easily:

```
final String url = "http://192.168.1.50:9000/greeting";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting.class);
```

Comment: You don't need to add MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to RestTemplate, if the Jackson Jar is in the classpath it is added automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The **Kotlin** way

```
val json = Gson().toJson(myObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Android 3.0 (API Level 11) Android has a more recent and improved JSON Parser.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

> Reads a JSON (RFC 4627) encoded value as a stream of tokens. This
>   stream includes both literal values (strings, numbers, booleans, and
>   nulls) as well as the begin and end delimiters of objects and arrays.
>   The tokens are traversed in depth-first order, the same order that
>   they appear in the JSON document. Within JSON objects, name/value
>   pairs are represented by a single token.

Comment: This is the opposite of what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you know this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourModelClassReference);
```

You might have forget to add **@Expose**

[image]