# Convert From json Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, object

I want to convert a json object to an array of object in android, 
I use that to convert to JSON `  JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

```
for (Modificateurs mod : this.getModificateurs()) {
    JSONObject pnObj = new JSONObject();
        pnObj.put(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEUR, mod.getModificateur());
        pnObj.put(Artifact.JSON_DATEMODIFICATION, mod.getDateModification());
        jsonArr.put(pnObj);
}
```

Now I want to do the inverse, please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert object to JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571092/convert-object-to-json-in-android)

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: i create a json object with arrays, now i want to do the inverse. For Example, when we have a simple string we use :  this.idAr = object.getString(".."); but i don't now haw to convert when i have a list of object

Comment: i would rather suggest you better appraoch, use google GSON librarym most apps uses it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String modificateur = obj.optString(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEUR);
    String date = obj.optString(Artifcat.JSON_DATEMODIFICATION);
    Modificateurs mod = new Modificateurs(modificateur, date);
    mods.add(mod);
}
```

Comment: how i take JsonArr ?

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it works. If not, please let me know.